# Using of a ViewControler directly in XIB File. (Monotouch)

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios

I'm developing apps with Monotouch and its working quit well.

When im working with View Controllers in Code wich load there Views directly from xib file, everything is working fine.

But i see that InterfaceBuilder also allows to put ViewControllers directly in a xib file. With this the interface Design would be much easier. But I don't know if this is supported via Monotouch, and when it is, how do I use it.

Maybe someone can help me???

Answer (score 2):

Under the "Add New" dialog, pick iPhone or iPad Controller under the MonoTouch section.  This will create a `YourController.cs`, `YourController.designer.cs`, and a `YourController.xib` file.

Beyond that, all you should have to do is edit the XIB file which has the view as you expect and the controller as the File's Owner.  If you hook up any outlets or actions, they will show up in the controller.  Outlets will be properties and actions will be partial methods.

Note that not every type of controller works properly (such as UITabBarController or UISplitViewController), I've not had any issues with UIViewController or UITableViewController.  For controllers that do not work in this way, it's generally just easier to create them in C#.

You can also set up additional controllers in the same XIB file.  To access them, you will have to create outlets.  Their views will show up for editing as you would expect in the UI tree within the XIB file.

Comment: I know this, but i want to create the viewcontroler in the xib file, not the iew. And i only want to have obe vie controler in that file, not one beside a view! Is this possible?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just make the view in the XIB file as well?  I'm not following why you would want to do that.  If you need a plain controller, just create it in C# with `new UIViewController();`

Comment: I dont need an empty Controller. I want to use the TabbarConroller for example, but i want to design the TabBarController in the Designer, not only a view.
Like in a objectiveC program, wher eyou can define the VieWControler in the MainWindow.xib

Comment: See the last paragraph on my answer.  In your main XIB file, just add the additional controller.  You will have to make an outlet to access the UITabBarController, however.  A UITabBarController also doesn't seem to work if it is the File's Owner, so there must be another controller as the root of the XIB file.  (it would have been nice if you had mentioned the tab bar controller in your question)